# Looks like the job listings page sort order by date is not working

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

The jobs listed are not sorted by date. When I click on the "most recent" button it does not list the items in descending order. But it works when I use the full search url with following parameters

```
http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=&type=&location=&range=20&distanceUnits=Km
```

What could be the problem? Could this issue be something similar to the one that I reported [earlier](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267104/why-the-most-recent-search-is-not-sorted-by-date).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the bug report! It was a bug in the button, not in the sorting logic. Should be fixed now.